# Getting error Unable to cast object of type 'System.DBNull' to type 'System.String'

Tags: c#, sql

My stored procedure returns `jsonresult` if an error occurs, but when data is updated I am getting this error:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.DBNull' to type 'System.String'

Can anyone please tell where is the problem in my c# code or my stored procedure?

sql:

```sql
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_UpdateCentralDeviceStatus]

    @pMacA NVARCHAR(30),
    @pCustCode NVARCHAR(15),
    @pStatus NVARCHAR(15),
    @pJsonResult NVARCHAR(MAX) out
    
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from

    SET NOCOUNT ON;
     DECLARE @p_CustId INT = 0;
     --DECLARE @pJsonResult NVARCHAR(MAX);
     DECLARE @p_Cust_Status NVARCHAR(20);

    BEGIN TRY

         -- To validate customer status
         SELECT @p_CustId = ID,
                @p_Cust_Status = [Status]
         FROM dbo.tblCustomer
         WHERE CustomerCode = @pCustCode;

        IF @p_CustId = 0
        BEGIN
            SELECT @pJsonResult =
            (
                SELECT 'ERROR' AS C_ERROR,
                       'Customer Not Registered' AS MSG
                    FOR JSON PATH, INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES
            );
            RAISERROR(@pJsonResult, 16, 1);
        END;

        IF @p_Cust_Status <> 'Active'
        BEGIN

            SELECT @pJsonResult =
            (
                SELECT 'ERROR' AS RESULT,
                       'Customer ' + @p_Cust_Status AS MSG
                FOR JSON PATH, INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES
            );
            RAISERROR(@pJsonResult, 16, 1);

        END;

        IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.tblCustomerCentralDevice WHERE refID_Customer = @p_CustId AND MACAddr = @pMacA)
        BEGIN

            SELECT @pJsonResult =
            (
                SELECT 'ERROR' AS C_ERROR,
                       'Device Not Registered' AS MSG
                FOR JSON PATH, INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES
            );
            RAISERROR(@pJsonResult, 16, 1);
        END;

    
        UPDATE MachineData
        SET MachineData.OnlineStatus = @pStatus
        FROM tblCustomerMachineData MachineData
        INNER JOIN tblCustomerMachine  Machine ON Machine.ID = MachineData.refID_CustomerMachine
        INNER JOIN tblCustomerCentralDevice CCtrlDevice ON CCtrlDevice.ID = Machine.refID_CentralDevice
        
        WHERE CCtrlDevice.MACAddr = @pMacA AND CCtrlDevice.refID_Customer=@p_CustId
     
   END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
         PRINT 'catch';
        SELECT @pJsonResult;
    END CATCH;
END;
```

c#:

```cs
    public string CentralDeviceStatusUpdate(JObject MachineInfo, Socket client)
        {
            string result = null;
            string connectionstatus = null;
            try
            {
                if (!IsConnected(client))
                {
                    connectionstatus = "Offline";
                }
                else
                {
                    connectionstatus = "Online";
                }

                SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(SqlconString);
                sqlCon.Open();

                SqlCommand sql_cmnd = new SqlCommand("SP_UpdateCentralDeviceStatus", sqlCon);
                sql_cmnd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                sql_cmnd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pMacA", "C82B9690AEFC");//MachineInfo["MAC"].ToString());
                sql_cmnd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pCustCode", "230006");// MachineInfo["Code"].ToString());
                sql_cmnd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pStatus", "Online");//connectionstatus);
                sql_cmnd.Parameters.Add("@pJsonResult", SqlDbType.Char, 500);
                sql_cmnd.Parameters["@pJsonResult"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
                sql_cmnd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                result = (string)sql_cmnd.Parameters["@pJsonResult"].Value;
               
                sqlCon.Close();

                IPHostEntry Entry = Dns.GetHostEntry(((IPEndPoint)client.RemoteEndPoint).Address.ToString());
                string HostName = Entry.HostName.ToString();
                //string HostName = "" ;

                AddToGrid(connectionstatus,clients.IndexOf(clientsocket), HostName, ((IPEndPoint)clientsocket.RemoteEndPoint).Address.ToString(),
                    GetMacAddress(((IPEndPoint)clientsocket.RemoteEndPoint).Address.ToString()));
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Log(ErrorMsg("Error receiving data: {0} " + ex.Message));
            }
            return result;
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        result = (string)sql_cmnd.Parameters["@pJsonResult"].Value;
```

try

```
        result = (string?)sql_cmnd.Parameters["@pJsonResult"].Value;
```

More description about **Introducing Nullable Reference Types in C#** see [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/nullable-reference-types-in-csharp/)

Answer (score 1):

Your `@JsonResult` is not initialized with data unless specific conditions are met within the stored procedure. To avoid this error, you should set an initial value to it, and I would also suggest setting a value to it if the update was successful.

That being said, here are three more problems with your code:

**First**, both `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand` implement the `IDisposable` interface and should be used with a `using` statement, i.e.

```
using(var con = new SqlConnection(...))
{

}
```

The `using` statement ensures that the sql connection will be properly disposed (and closed as a result) even in case of an exception in the code. For more information, read the [Remarks section in official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection?view=dotnet-plat-ext-8.0#remarks).

**Second**, You really should avoid using `sp_` as a prefix for stored procedures. This prefix is used by Microsoft for the already built-in stored procedures in the Master database. This is a well-known issue and is covered in multiple blogs, including Aaron Bertrand's [Is the sp_ prefix still a no-no?](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix) from 10 years ago.

**Third**, you should stop using `AddWithValue()`. The problem with `AddWithValue()` is that you're forcing ADO.Net to infer the type of the parameters. Most of the time ADO.Net will get it right, but sometimes it will not, leading to unexpected bug that might results in run-time errors, or worst - data lose. For more information, read Dan Guzman's [AddWithValue is Evil](https://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/) blog post.

Comment: still getting error on this line  result = (string)sql_cmnd.Parameters["@pJsonResult"].Value;

Comment: i'm returning value if data not exists than error return from procedure and exits than update in table and return customer id but getting error when update data

Comment: Add to your stored procedure `SET @pJsonResult = ''` at the start of the procedure and see what happens.